# Создание объектов COM в потоках

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, com

Правильно ли я понимаю что объекты ADO надо создавать не в конструкторе потока а в Execute потока? И почему именно так? И где именно об этом более подробно почитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что теоретически создавать в одном потоке, а использовать в другом возможно, не стоит таким приемом пользоваться за исключением случаев, когда явно указано, что методы объекта потокобезопасны. Причин несколько:

1. Один поток не знает, что сейчас делается в другом, если не используются средства синхронизации (критические секции / мьютексы / евенты и т.д.). Таким образом, обращаясь во вторичном потоке к объекту, созданному в главном, можно получить "конфликт доступа", когда одну и ту же область памяти модифицируют одновременно оба потока. В конечном итоге это может привести к порче памяти со всеми вытекающими. Особенно показательна в этом плане работа со строками.
2. Вы ничего не знаете о внутренностях объекта. Даже если "снаружи" он выглядит однопоточным, не факт, что такое правило распространяется на его внутренности. Вполне возможно, что внутри него для выполнения действий создаются дополнительные потоки, а события вызываются через средства синхронизации. Таким образом, создав объект в главном потоке, а пытаясь использовать его во вторичном вы будете принимать события в контексте главного потока и это уже приведет к п.1. К тому же объект может создавать окна и осуществлять некоторые действия отправкой оконных сообщений. В случае с вызовом вами метода объекта это будет потокобезопасно, а в случае возбуждения события этим способом - уже нет. Правда, чтобы оконный объект работал в потоке, во многих случаях нужно создавать в этом потоке очередь сообщений.
3. И самое главное. Есть как минимум негласное правило (хотя возможно, оно и документировано): где создали, там и использовать. Исключения, естественно, есть - если свойство/метод указаны как потокобезопасные, или в описании события есть запись "вызывается в контексте потока ХХХ".

В случае с документацией по компонентам ADO - есть явное указание, что некоторые события будут вызываться в дополнительных потоках, если указаны флаги AsyncExecute, AsyncFetch.

Почитать можно, например, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`TADOQuery`, например, замечательно создаётся в конструкторе потока и очень даже работает.